# Wordpress, editing blog index link

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im trying to edit my webisites blog that I inherited from a creator I have no contact with. I have been fiddling with the site for a little more than a week but I don't know how to edit the links in the blog index.

Here is the link to my site's blog:
http://bestdetails.com/blog/

As you can see the box is a link to the whole article, and in the article if you scroll down you can see the tags for the post.

I want the tags inside the box to show on the blog index page instead.

I want to put the tags where the red circle is:
[image]

I know that you can edit the blog in the blog.php, but I don't know what code or where in the HTML text to put that code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the post tags, you have the function [get_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags);

It is called this way:

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

The place to edit will depend on your Theme, it can be in the index, the page.php or the blog.php. Take a look at your Settings -> Reading and see what page is acting as home and which is acting as blog. After that go to pages and see what template is associated, if any.